# How do I programmatically set a password in ruby-sftp

Tags: ruby, security, cron, sftp, daemon

I am writing my own custom backup program that will backup my data to a remote sftp site.However, I am planning to make it run as a background daemon and whenever ruby-sftp makes a connection to an sftp site, it prompts for a a password which I wouldn't be able to put in. So is there a way to make it accept a programmatic password?

Answer (score 0):

If you want this to happen without storing your passwords in a reversible manner the easiest option you have is likely using a certificate for your ssh authentication. Something similar to [this tutorial](http://tutorialgenius.blogspot.com/2012/02/unixlinux-setting-up-public-key.html)

This question is likely more suited for SuperUser.com